# Hacer un método que capture el IMEI según el API de Android

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo un problema. lo que pasa es que tengo una aplicación que captura el `imei` para poder loguearse, y el método que uso es

```
    private String a() {

        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String imei =tm.getDeviceId();
        return imei;

    }
```

pero ese método solo sirve para dispositivos menores que 6.0. y tengo celulares con 4.4, 5.1 y 6.0. luego implementé el siguiente código.

```
    public String obtenerImei()
    {
        String imei="";
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);
            imei="";
        } else {
           imei= a();
        }

        return imei;
    }

    private String a() {

        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String imei =tm.getDeviceId(); // Obtiene el imei  or  "352319065579474";
        return imei;

    }
```

pero este último no funciona en los APIS menores que 23 obviamente, ¿Cómo implementar un solo método para que reconozca la captura del imei en ambos casos?

---

este es mi último código

```
public String obtenerImei()
{

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT  < Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    {
        //Menores a Android 6.0
        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String imei =tm.getDeviceId();
        return imei;
    }
    else
    {
        // Mayores a Android 6.0
        String imei="";
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);
            imei="";
        } else {
            imei= a();
        }

        return imei;

    }
}

private String a() {

    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String imei =tm.getDeviceId(); // Obtiene el imei  or  "352319065579474";
    return imei;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes validar de esta forma mediante la clase [**Build.VERSION**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html):

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT  < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) //Version SDK menor a Android 6.0
{
      //Menores a Android 6.0
}
else
{
    // Mayores a Android 6.0
}
```

[Aquí](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html) puedes ver todos los [VERSION_CODE](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html) para que valides dependiendo de la API.

Esta sería una forma como lo realizarías:

```
  public String obtenerImei()
    {

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT  < Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        {
            //Menores a Android 6.0
            String imei= getIMEI();
            return imei;
        }
        else
        {
            // Mayores a Android 6.0
            String imei="";
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);
                imei="";
            } else {
                imei= getIMEI();
            }

            return imei;

        }
    }

    private String getIMEI() {

        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String imei =tm.getDeviceId(); // Obtiene el imei  or  "352319065579474";
        return imei;

    }
```

Comment: acabo de responder cómo seria. creo que le falta algo.... @Elenasys

Comment: @ICRUZ exacto lo que agregaste sería correcto.

Comment: disculpa, estaba ultimando detalles en la app. Sí, es la correcta. ya lo había escrito con el IF que me pasaste, pero igual todos los créditos son tuyos, muchas gracias de todas maneras. Espero que este código les sirva mucho a otros. 

nota: el retorno del imei es en string para validarlo en la base de datos, adáptenlo a su manera.

Comment: @ICRUZ como curiosidad el IMEI lo necesitarías para que razón en tu aplicación? identificar usuario único u otra razón?

Comment: sí, identificar usuario único